# Performance optimization for std::string

Tags: c++, optimization

When I did some performance test in my app I noticed a difference in the following code (Visual Studio 2010).

Slower version

```
while(heavyloop)
{
   if(path+node+"/" == curNode)
   {
        do something
   }
}
```

This will cause some extra mallocs for the resulting string to be generated.

In order to avoid these mallocs, I changed it in the following way:

```
std::string buffer;
buffer.reserve(500);   // Big enough to hold all combinations without the need of malloc

while(heavyloop)
{
   buffer = path;
   buffer += node;
   buffer += "/";

   if(buffer == curNode)
   {
        do something
   }
}
```

While the second version looks a bit more awkward compared to the first version it's still readable enough. What I was wondering though is, wether this kind of optimization is an oversight on part of the compiler, or if this always has to be done manually. Since it only changes the order of allocations I would expect that the compiler could also figure it out on it's own. On the other hand, certain conditions have to be met, to really make it an optimization, which may not neccessarily be fullfilled, but if the conditions are not, the code would at least perform as good as the first version. Are newer versions of Visual Studio better in this regard?

A more complete version which shows the difference (SSCE):

```
std::string gen_random(std::string &oString, const int len)
{
    static const char alphanum[] =
        "0123456789"
        "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    oString = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        oString += alphanum[rand() % (sizeof(alphanum) - 1)];
    }

    return oString;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    clock_t start = clock();
    std::string s = "/";
    size_t adds = 0;
    size_t subs = 0;
    size_t max_len = 0;

    s.reserve(100000);

    for(size_t i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
        std::string t1;
        std::string t2;
        if(rand() % 2)
        {
            // Slow version
            //s += gen_random(t1, (rand() % 15)+3) + "/" + gen_random(t2, (rand() % 15)+3);

            // Fast version
            s += gen_random(t1, (rand() % 15)+3);
            s += "/";
            s += gen_random(t2, (rand() % 15)+3);
            adds++;
        }
        else
        {
            subs++;
            size_t pos = s.find_last_of("/", s.length()-1);
            if(pos != std::string::npos)
                s.resize(pos);

            if(s.length() == 0)
                s = "/";
        }

        if(max_len < s.length())
            max_len = s.length();
    }
    std::cout << "Elapsed: " << clock() - start << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Added: " << adds << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Subtracted: " << subs << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Max: " << max_len << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

On my system I get about 1 second difference between the two (tested with gcc this time but there doesn't seem to be any notable difference to Visual Studio there):

```
Elapsed: 2669
Added: 500339
Subtracted: 499661
Max: 47197

Elapsed: 3417
Added: 500339
Subtracted: 499661
Max: 47367
```

Comment: `std::string` is not designed very well, for historical reasons.   Many large projects have found considerable speed-up after replacing their strings with a custom string class, or going over their string-handling code and rewriting to eliminate temporary copies.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that. In some cases I replaced it with vector<char> which performed much better (but the code was not as nice of course. :) ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your slow version may be rewritten as

```
while(heavyloop)
{
   std::string tempA = path + node;
   std::string tempB = tempA + "/";

   if(tempB == curNode)
   {
        do something
   }
}
```

Yes, it is not a full analog, but makes temporary objects more visible.

See two temporary objects: `tempA` and `tempB`. They are created because [std::string::operator+](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B) always generates new `std::string` object. This is how `std::string` is designed. A compiler won't be able to optimize this code.

There is a technique in C++ called [expression templates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_templates) to address this issue, but again, it it done on library level.

Comment: Your "rewrite" isn't equivalent: in OP's code, `path + node` has its `operator+` called with `"/"` ; there is no distinct `tempA` and `tempB`.  Closer would be changing the `tempB` line to: `tempA += "/"`., or using `tempB = std::move(tempA) + "/"`

Comment: The code is close enough, only reversed. I noticed that creation of the temporary when I tested this originally, and it compiled to `node += "/"; path += node;`

Comment: @M.M we can't call `operator+=` for `tempA` the same way as we can't get non const reference of `tempA` object, so the code is close enough.

Comment: You can call operators on temporary objects

Comment: @M.M yes, but only const operators, and `+=` is not the case, as it modifies  an object. Anyway, we can't call `+=` when there is `+` in the code. They are completely different operators.

Comment: No, non-const operators can be called on temporary objects; and the usual implementation of `+` is implemented by calling `+=`

Answer (score 2):

For class types (like `std::string`) there is no requirement that the conventional relationship between operator `+` and operator `+=` be honoured like you expect.   There is certainly no requirement that `a = a + b` and `a += b` have the same net effect, since `operator=()`, `operator+()` and `operator+=()` can all potentially be implemented individually, and not work together in tandem.

As such, a compiler would be semantically incorrect if it replaced

```
if(path+node+"/" == curNode)
```

with

```
std::string buffer = path;
buffer += node;
buffer += "/";
if (buffer == curNode)
```

If there was some constraint in the standard, for example a fixed relationship between overloaded `operator+()` and overloaded `operator+=()` then the two fragments of code would have the same net effect.   However, there is no such constraint, so the compiler is not permitted to do such substitutions.   The result would be changing meaning of the code.

Comment: If two (well-defined) fragments of code can potentially have different meaning, a compiler cannot substitute one for the other.

Answer (score 1):

path+node+"/"  will allocate a temp variable string to compare with curNode,it's the c++ implement.